# When inserting new columns in a datatable in VB 2010, how do I update the SQL Server 2008 Database?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

Using VB 2010 and SQL Server 2008:

I am able to insert new rows, delete rows, and update data in a datatable, and use a data adapter to update the database without any issues. When I try to add new columns, the column appears in the data table, but it does not update to the database. I currently am using the DataAdapter.Update(DataTable) Method.

My code is as follows:

```
Dim dcNewColumn As New DataColumn
dcNewColumn.ColumnName = strClassColumnName
m_DataTable.Columns.Add(dcNewColumn)
m_DataTable.Row(intCurrentRow).Item(strClassColumnName) = strClassName
dcNewColumn = Nothing

m_DA.Update(m_DataTable)
```

Is there a different method to updating the database when inserting new columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [`ALTER TABLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) sql command.
Or the [SQLDMO Columns Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135184%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)  (Please check the notice at the start of the page)

An ALTER TABLE Command  to add a column could be coded in this way

```
Dim cn As SqlConnection
Dim cmd As SqlCommand
Using cn = GetConnection()
    cn.Open()
    Using cmd = new SqlCommand()
         cmd.Connection = cn
         cmd.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE myTable ADD aNewColumn VARCHAR(20) NULL"
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: I am trying to use this code, but I am having a bit of trouble. My connection is already opened before this because I am using it throughout this procedure. I am using the following:

    Dim cmd As SQLCommand
    Using cn
        Using cmd = new SQLCommand()
            cmd.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE Interval ADD " & strClassName & " Text NULL"
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using

I am getting an "ExecuteNonQuery: Connection Property Has Not Been Initialized" error. Any ideas on what I can do to correct this?

Comment: Wow, I also am not quite sure the best way to reply to the answers. Is there a better method to show my code block?

Comment: Sorry, forget to bind the connection to the actual SqlCommand, answer updated

Comment: You could try to update the original question, but the error message is enough to understand my mistake.

Comment: Aha! Awesome sir. Thank you for your help. I greatly appreciate it! I'd like to vote the answer up, but I need a few more reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a new column is not an update. You can issue some sql to change the structure of the table in the database e.g.

```
Alter Table MyTable AddMyNewColumn int null
```

if you have the relevant permissions.

Aside from admin type functionality, this isn't something you'd normally do though.