# VB.net Adding column to sql server by DataAdapter

Tags: vb.net

I'm using MS SQLServer 2012.

In my current project, I need to insert a column to the database by run time. I'm using DataAdapter everywhere that needs to work with database and it works fine. However, I cannot figure out a way to insert new column to the datatable.

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168909/when-inserting-new-columns-in-a-datatable-in-vb-2010-how-do-i-update-the-sql-se) but it does not use DataAdapter. Though I can get on with it, I want to use DataAdapter if possible since my data handling class is built around DataAdapter

So, is it possible to use DataAdapter to insert new column into SQL datatable? Or I have to use a SqlConnection ?

Comment: `DataAdapter` only serves as a reader/writer, to make schema changes in the DB you probably need to run separate SQL commands.

Comment: A data adapter is used to retrieve data from the database into a `DataTable` and save changes to that data back to the database.  It is not for anything else.  To make a schema change, you would need to create a `SqlCommand` and call `ExecuteNonQuery`. That said, why do you think you need to add a column?  Maybe it's legitimate but I've seen plenty of people think they need to add columns at run time only because their database is poorly designed.

Comment: By the way, if you're using as `SqlDataAdapter` then you're already using a `SqlConnection`, so your last question doesn't make sense.  A data adapter groups four command objects and each of those commands has a connection - usually the same one for all four.  When you call `Fill`, the `SelectCommand` is invoked to retrieve data and that data is retrieved over the connection.  When you call `Update`, the `InsertCommand`, `UpdateCommand` and `DeleteCommand` are invoked as required to save the changes back over that connection.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I need to add at run time because I'm working on a table that represent chemical procedures - the textile dyeing formulas to be more exact - in which each column is used to store the amount of one chemical ingredient of the formula. Sometime, new ingredients are used and thus the need of new columns to store their data. I cannot predict which ingredient will be used in the next year,or two, and of course I cannot let my program to just work with some fixed ingredients, that's why I need to change the columns in run time.

Comment: It sounds like your database is poorly designed.  It would make more sense to have a table for the ingredients.  That way, each time you need to add a new ingredient, you only have to add a new row instead of a new column.  That's the way it should be.  You can then have another table for procedures and another that joins the procedures to the ingredients.  When the ingredients change for a procedure, you simply add a new row to the ingredient table if it's a totally new ingredient and then add a new row to the join table to indicate that that ingredient is used in that procedure.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your suggestion. I'll try this approach.